# Check if a string (word) is a subset of another string (word) independent of sequence

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check in a string if it is a subset of another string. But not in sequence.

Ie = "ABC" in "BAC" = true.

What I have done so far is sort both strings alphabetically (once off exercise done in vba), then check with "find(a,b)" but this does not quite work:

"hour" is then not a subset of "dffhioru" because i find for "hour" but the letter sequence is hioru whilst hour is horu when sorted.

I ideally want to *not* use vba here for speed purposes, but if there is not such a function then so be it.

Comment: Let me see if I got it. You just want to check if every character from string A is in string B?

Comment: What happens with words with repeated letters? For example, is "TAGGED" in "GATED" = true? If not, this would complicate the matter...

Comment: Yeah Ideally Tagged is not in Gated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without VBA by finding each letter in separate columns and then joining them if the string length matches the original string.

Find formula in cell E1 then autofill to O?

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND(MID($B2,E$1,1),$A2,1) > 0,MID($B2,E$1,1),""),"")
```

Concatinate formula in C2 and autofill down to the end of your word list.

```
=IF(COUNTA(E2:O2)-COUNTBLANK(E2:O2)=LEN(A2),CONCATENATE(E2,F2,G2,H2,I2,J2,K2,L2,M2,N2,O2),"")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm going to test this, it looks really promising

Comment: This has the issue that it does not quite work when there is duplicates in Column B. But a little bit of tinkering got me to the solution.  Which is to alphabetise Column A's words (this was done via vba, but once done it's complete). Then I alphabetise my input word (column B) and then I can use the excel find function to find my possible solution. The length is then not needed to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
Sub CheckString()
Dim myChar As String
Dim i As Long

Range("C1").Value = ""

For i = 1 To Len(Range("A1"))
    myChar = Mid(Range("A1").Text, i, 1)
    If InStr(1, Range("B1").Text, myChar, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i


Range("C1").Value = "OK"

End Sub
```

Basically what it does is loop trough every char in first string (here in cell A1) and checks if it's in the second string (cell B1). If a char is not found the code stops, if all of the chars are found it puts "OK" into cell C1. This should get you going.

EDIT: To address Storax's point I have changed the code a little.

First it checks the length of both strings - if the first one is longer automatically it's not a subset. If it's not the case it stores the second string in memory as myText and takes out the chars one by one. And now if all the chars can be taken out it meant the first string is a subset and the code puts "OK" into cell C1.

```
Sub CheckString()
Dim myChar, myText As String
Dim i, charPos As Long

Range("C1").Value = ""

myText = Range("B1").Text

If Len(Range("A1").Text) > Len(Range("B1").Text) Then Exit Sub

For i = 1 To Len(Range("A1"))

    myChar = Mid(Range("A1").Text, i, 1)
    charPos = InStr(1, myText, myChar, vbTextCompare)

    If charPos = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        myText = Left(myText, charPos - 1) & Mid(myText, charPos + 1, Len(myText))
    End If
Next i


    Range("C1").Value = "OK"


End Sub
```

Comment: You should clear `C1` at the beginning of your code.  Otherwise, if you change the values in `A1` or `B1` such that the test fails, the previous `OK` will still be there.